# HTML Validator unescaped & which should be as amp

Tags: php, html, validation, tidy

I keep getting this error on line 36 in my PHP product, line 36 is this: (Its an ecommerce site)

```
<?php
include '../inc/theprodukts.php';
?>
```

When I move the include a few lines down, it moves the error line, so the error is obviously in my theprodukts.php which looks as following.

```
<?php
$CatID = $_GET['cat'];

$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$db = "nettbutikk";

$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if ($CatID == "all")
{
$checkproducts = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkproducts))
{


echo "<div class='produktboks'>";
echo "<p class='produktnavn'>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";
echo "<div class='photos'><img alt='' width='130px' height='90px' src='../bilder/produktbilder/" . $row['img'] . "' />";
echo "<p>pris : " . $row['price'] . " Kr</p>";
echo "<a href='../sider/productdetail.php?productid=" . $row['ID'] . "&?cat=" . $row['cat'] . "'><img src='../bilder/detaljer.gif' alt=''width='53' height='19'></a>";
echo "<a href='../inc/addtocart.php?productid=" . $row['ID'] . "'><img src='../bilder/cart.gif' alt='' width='71' height='19'></a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
}else{
$checkproducts = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products
WHERE cat=" . $CatID);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkproducts))
{
echo "<div class='produktboks'>";
echo "<p class='produktnavn'>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";
echo "<div class='photos'><img width='130px' height='90px' src='../bilder/produktbilder/" . $row['img'] . "' />";
echo "<p>pris : " . $row['price'] . " Kr</p>";
echo "<a href='../sider/productdetail.php?productid=" . $row['ID'] . "&?cat=" . $row['cat'] . "'><img src='../bilder/detaljer.gif' alt=''width='53' height='19'></a>";
echo "<a href='../inc/addtocart.php?productid=" . $row['ID'] . "'><img src='../bilder/cart.gif' alt='' width='71' height='19'></a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error? Show it.

Comment: Line 36, Column 208: NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES

Comment: …bilder/../produktbilder/produkt1.png' /><p>pris : 3369 Kr</p><a href='../sider…

Comment: `&?` should be `&amp;` - twice. _The query string of an URL has the format `?a=1&b=2&c=3` where `&` should be escaped as entity `&amp;`

Comment: If you are running an HTML validator on your script's *output*, the line number cannot refer to your PHP *source code*.

Comment: Furthermore use `$CatID = intval($_GET['cat']);` or so ("all") to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='../sider/productdetail.php?productid=" . $row['ID'] . "&?cat=" . $row['cat'] . "'><img src='../bilder/detaljer.gif' alt=''width='53' height='19'></a>";
```

Note the & in the url buildup.

change it to this:

```
echo "<a href='../sider/productdetail.php?productid=" . $row['ID'] . "&amp;?cat=" . $row['cat'] . "'><img src='../bilder/detaljer.gif' alt=''width='53' height='19'></a>";
```

and it is also like that within the while loop.

Comment: What about this ..  line 36 column 600 - Warning: <img> attribute "width" has invalid value "130px"

Comment: within the attributes should be `width="130"` in CSS it should be `width: 130px;`